# How to get a UITextView to autosize within a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Setup:  I have a `UITextView` inside a `UITableViewCell`'s `contentView`.  I want it to take up the full size of the cell.  I create the text view like so:

```
UITextView *textView = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,268,43)] autorelease];
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
textView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
textView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

And I override heightForRowAtIndexPath to return 200 for that row.

The background color is just so I can tell where it is.  The cell seems to be automatically sizing it correctly upon first view.  However, I need it to continue to resize it correctly while autorotating the interface, which only seems to work sometimes, and only when I'm not editing the textView.  Other times, it resizes the view to have a very small height (looks like -1), or makes it too wide, or just doesn't even resize it at all.

I've tried overriding layoutSubviews in the cell and just do nothing, but even that doesn't stop the view from resizing all over the place.

I've been hacking away at this for awhile now, but still have found no solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UITableViewCell has a fixed height, the height provided by the UITableView's delegate. When you rotate your device, the height of the row will never change, unless you call `-reloadData` on your tableView. I'd get rid of the autoresizing and manage it yourself.

When you init your textField, you can easily set the frame to `CGRectZero`. Then implement `-layoutSubviews` (and call super in that method, *before* setting the frames of your subviews) and set the frame of the UITextField according to the `contentRect` property of the cell.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if(self = [super ...]){ // or -initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: whatever you want
        _textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]; // Instance variable
        // Probably not needed to set autoresizing mask
    }

    return self;
}
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    _textView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.contentRect.size.width, self.contentRect.size.height); // Adjust as needed
}
```